# Redshift does not display the correct timestamp when using a timestamp column and parquet files

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-redshift, dask, parquet

Using redshift copy command to insert parquet files to redshift.

Once the data is loaded the data for my timestamp column 'last_run' is wrong.
I should expect a timestamp like `2024-03-19 18:19:29.892934+00:00` but end up with `96039-03-05 11:02:28582`. When I check the datatype in with parquet I get `last_run datetime64[ns, UTC]` The data type for the redshift column is `timestamp` .

Any suggestions on debugging this or fixing this problem?